# How long is the information on Facebook stored?

Tags: privacy, data-leakage, facebook, deletion

I was wondering how long Facebook stores our photos and posts?

I hear two theories, one saying it is around half a year, after which all the data centers are going to erase our data. The other one says never (more conspiracy theory, however maybe not so abstract, there is no guarantee).

So what are the facts, or the most precise approximations?

Comment: If you read the work of [**Max Schrems**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Schrems) you may conclude your Facebook data is there forever whatever you do.

Answer (score 1):

If your account is active, deactivated or in remembrance mode after your death, it stores all your data indefinitely.
If you delete your account the information [should be deleted within 90 days](https://m.facebook.com/help/224562897555674).

> When you delete your account, people won't be able to see it on Facebook. It may take up to 90 days to delete all of the things you've posted, like your photos, status updates or other data stored in backup systems

Although there are some exceptions to this rule.

> Some of the things you do on Facebook aren’t stored in your account. For example, a friend may still have messages from you even after you delete your account. That information remains after you delete your account.

It should be noted however that Facebook isn't the most transparent of companies and they change their terms of service regularly. In addition any data that Facebook hands over to 3rd parties will probably not be covered by any of their own data retention policies.

[This artical suggests that pictures will be deleted within 30 days](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/01/ask-ars-does-facebook-auto-delete-content-after-a-certain-period-of-time/). It is also explains some of the nuances behind Facebooks data retention policies.